# Back button of Toolbar doesn't work

Tags: android, android-toolbar

The detailed activity of my app looks like this.

[image: detail activity]

When I add the menu items, the back button of the toolbar doesn’t work. If I take them out, everything works fine. Here is my code for that specific activity.

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView mImageView;
TextView mTitle;
TextView mDate;
TextView mDescription;

private String newsTitle;
private String newsImage;
private String newsDate;
private String newsDescription;
private static String NEWS_SHARE_HASHTAG ="#PopularMoviesApp";
private String date1;
private String date2;
private String newsUrl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    Intent i = getIntent();

    mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.detail_image_view);
    mTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_title);
    mDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_publish_date);
    mDescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_description);

    newsImage = i.getStringExtra("image");
    newsTitle = i.getStringExtra("title");
    newsDate = i.getStringExtra("date");
    newsDescription = i.getStringExtra("description");
    newsUrl = i.getStringExtra("url");

    date1 = newsDate.substring(0,10);
    date2 = newsDate.substring(11,19);

    Picasso.with(this).load(newsImage)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_broken_image)
            .into(mImageView);

    mTitle.setText(newsTitle);
    mDescription.setText(newsDescription);
    mDate.setText(date2 + ", " + date1);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail_menu,menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.detail_browser_btn){
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(newsUrl));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.detail_share_btn){
        Intent shareIntent = createShareNewsIntent();
        startActivity(shareIntent);
    }

    return true;
}

private Intent createShareNewsIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
            .setType("text/plain")
            .setText(mTitle + NEWS_SHARE_HASHTAG + "\n\n\n" + newsTitle
                    + "\n\n\n" + newsDescription
                    + "\n\n\n" + newsDate)
            .getIntent();

    return shareIntent;
}
}
```

How can this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
if(item.getItemId() ==android.R.id.home){
  onBackPressed();
}
```

to your `onOptionsItemSelected` override.

This way, when you're tapping that button you'll invoke the `onBackPressed` method, which is the default action to go back (a cleaner solution than brutally invoking `finish()`)

That should do it.

Comment: It's a good answer, but I don't think it's the professional way to do it...

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == android.R.id.home){
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it out with this code:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way in itemselectedmethod

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.homeAsUp:
                finish();
                return true;

        }
        finish();
        return true;
    }
```